# What is the best way to store dates formatted as YYYY-MM-DD in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, date

I'm using MongoDB and it looks like they only have one date type format. This works fine when storing things like timestamps that are formatted as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`. The problem I'm having is that I only need to save the date as `YYYY-MM-DD`. We can't save dates as an ISO string because we have international customers and we need certain data to be dated absolutely (e.g., 2020-11-14), regardless of where the user is located. So the question is, what is the best way to save a date in MongoDB as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is helpful for you or not but you can store the date in the default format ( YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ ) but at the time you access it you can split it like this :

```
yourDate.split("T")[0];
```

it will give only YYYY-MM-DD date format.

Comment: The problem with that is javascript auto-converts the date to the users timezone on their local device. I need a way to save and query by ```YYYY-MM-DD```. By the time I split the date it has already converted to their timezone and may be a day off what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

You should **never(!)** store date/time values as strings, use proper `Date` objects.

This does not apply only to MongoDB, it is valid for almost any database. Here on Stack Overflow you find hundreds or even thousands of questions where people have problems because they store date values as strings. Sorting, filtering, etc. works much better with the proper date data type.

If you are not interested in the time part then simply set it to 00:00:00.

Internally MongoDB stores dates as number of Milliseconds from `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. When you see `ISODate("2020-11-15T12:50:00.000Z")` then this is just the default **display** format of your client application (e.g. mongo shell).

If you are not satisfied with this default display format then use functions like
[$dateToString()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) or you can use libraries like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/), which is even more powerful.

Internally MongoDB stores date always as UTC time, i.e. it does not preserve the input time zone. If you need to preserve the input time zone, then you have to store it in a separate field. However, usually the desired output formate is just the current local time zone, so typically you don't have to preserve the input time zone.

Comment: Doesn't MySQL have a Date type formatted as ```YYYY-MM-DD```? I'm looking for something similar in MongoDB.

Comment: Like almost all other databases MySQL has an [internal format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html) to store date/time values. Again, what you see is just the default display format!